# How to get some random numbers printing continually in the console?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My problem is that when I am trying to use Unity to spawn some objects at randomized locations, for some unknown reason, the location of those spawned objects is the same location.

I tried to add Thread.Sleep() to my code and the location will be randomized.

Here is an example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mytest = new Program();

        Console.WriteLine(mytest.test());
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Console.WriteLine(mytest.test());
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Console.WriteLine(mytest.test());
        Thread.Sleep(500);

    }

    public int test()
    {
    Random random = new Random();
    int testrandom = random.Next(5, 100);
    return testrandom;
    }

}
```

I don't want to use Thread.Sleep() all the time, is there a way to get past this problem?

While using debugging, I found that without using Thread.Sleep(), the local variable testrandom will be randomly updated as testrandom = 30,testrandom=32,testrandom=13..., but the result is different, the result is testrandom=30 and repeats itself 3 times. Can someone tell me why is this happening? Maybe it runs too fast?

Comment: don't know why it won't let me add pictures

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). improving the quality of your question _dramatically_ improves your chance of getting quality answers. (for starters: ***don't*** try to include code and other text-based information as picture.)

Comment: Please don't add code as pictures!

Comment: "_don't know why it won't let me add pictures_" please dont. The code should be included as text in the question. Add images only when the image helps clarifying the problem.

Comment: You probably initialize a `new Random()` every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**.NET** Random class is seeded by system clock if no explicit seed is given, so if you create new instances in short time apart from each other each instance will give you same number. This is also reason why adding sleep between calls to `mytest.test()` mitigates problem, as system clock has advanced by the time `Thread.Sleep` is over.
You should reuse same instance of Random, and use that instance every time:

```
class Program
{
    private Random random = new Random();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mytest = new Program();

        Console.WriteLine(mytest.test());
        Console.WriteLine(mytest.test());
        Console.WriteLine(mytest.test());
    }

    public int test()
    {
    int testrandom = random.Next(5, 100);
    return testrandom;
    }

}
```

Also, you can declare your `test()` method and Random instance as static, so you don't have to create instance of Program-class:

```
class Program
{
    private static Random random = new Random();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(test());
        Console.WriteLine(test());
        Console.WriteLine(test());
    }

    public static int test()
    {
        int testrandom = random.Next(5, 100);
        return testrandom;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you @JM Gelilio for fixing formatting :)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I suppose the problem is caused by initializing a new Random() every time, with the same seed, it will generate the same number. The best way to correct this issue is initialize random() only once, so I won't get the same number over and over again.